# boost::asio write: Broken pipe

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, boost-asio

I have a `TCP` server that handles new connections, when there's a new connection two threads will be created (`std::thread`, detached).

```
void Gateway::startServer(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, unsigned short port) {

    tcp::acceptor TCPAcceptor(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port));

    bool UARTToWiFiGatewayStarted = false;

    for (;;) { std::cout << "\nstartServer()\n";

        auto socket(std::shared_ptr<tcp::socket>(new tcp::socket(io_service)));

        /*!
         * Accept a new connected WiFi client.
         */
        TCPAcceptor.accept(*socket);

        socket->set_option( tcp::no_delay( true ) );

        // This will set the boolean `Gateway::communicationSessionStatus` variable to true.
        Gateway::enableCommunicationSession();

        // start one thread
        std::thread(WiFiToUARTWorkerSession, socket, this->SpecialUARTPort, this->SpecialUARTPortBaud).detach();


        // start the second thread
        std::thread(UARTToWifiWorkerSession, socket, this->UARTport, this->UARTbaud).detach();
    }
}
```

The first of two worker functions look like this (here I'm reading using the shared socket):

```
void Gateway::WiFiToUARTWorkerSession(std::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> socket, std::string SpecialUARTPort, unsigned int baud) {
    std::cout << "\nEntered: WiFiToUARTWorkerSession(...)\n";

    std::shared_ptr<FastUARTIOHandler> uart(new FastUARTIOHandler(SpecialUARTPort, baud));

    try {
        while(true == Gateway::communicationSessionStatus) { std::cout << "WiFi->UART\n";

            unsigned char WiFiDataBuffer[max_incoming_wifi_data_length];

            boost::system::error_code error;

            /*!
             * Read the TCP data.
             */
            size_t length = socket->read_some(boost::asio::buffer(WiFiDataBuffer), error);

            /*!
             * Handle possible read errors.
             */
            if (error == boost::asio::error::eof) {
                // this will set the shared boolean variable from "true" to "false", causing the while loop (from the both functions and threads) to stop.
                Gateway::disableCommunicationSession();
                break; // Connection closed cleanly by peer.
            }
            else if (error) {
                Gateway::disableCommunicationSession();
                throw boost::system::system_error(error); // Some other error.
            }

            uart->write(WiFiDataBuffer, length);
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception &exception) {
        std::cerr << "[APP::exception] Exception in thread: " << exception.what() << std::endl;
    }

    std::cout << "\nExiting: WiFiToUARTWorkerSession(...)\n";
}
```

And the second one (here I'm writing using the thread-shared socket):

```
void Gateway::UARTToWifiWorkerSession(std::shared_ptr<tcp::socket> socket, std::string UARTport, unsigned int baud) {
    std::cout << "\nEntered: UARTToWifiWorkerSession(...)\n";

    /*!
     * Buffer used for storing the UART-incoming data.
     */
    unsigned char UARTDataBuffer[max_incoming_uart_data_length];
    std::vector<unsigned char> outputBuffer;

    std::shared_ptr<FastUARTIOHandler> uartHandler(new FastUARTIOHandler(UARTport, baud));

    while(true == Gateway::communicationSessionStatus) { std::cout << "UART->WiFi\n";

        /*!
         * Read the UART-available data.
         */
        auto bytesReceived = uartHandler->read(UARTDataBuffer, max_incoming_uart_data_length);


        /*!
         * If there was some data, send it over TCP.
         */
        if(bytesReceived > 0) {
            boost::asio::write((*socket), boost::asio::buffer(UARTDataBuffer, bytesReceived));

            std::cout << "\nSending data to app...\n";
        }
    }

    std::cout << "\nExited: UARTToWifiWorkerSession(...)\n";
}
```

For stopping this two threads I do the following thing: from the `WiFiToUARTWorkerSession(...)` function, if the `read(...)` fails (there's an error like `boost::asio::error::eof`, or any other error) I set the `Gateway::communicationSessionStatus` boolean switch (which is shared (global) by the both functions) to `false`, this way the functions should return, and the threads should be killed gracefully.

When I'm connecting for the first time, this works well, but when I'm disconnecting from the server, the execution flow from the `WiFiToUARTWorkerSession(...)` goes through `else if (error)` condition, it sets the `while` condition variable to `false`, and then it throws `boost::system::system_error(error)` (which actually means `Connection reset by peer`).

Then when I'm trying to connect again, I got the following exception and the program terminates:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'boost::exception_detail::clone_impl<boost::exception_detail::error_info_injector<boost::system::system_error> >'
  what():  write: Broken pipe
```

What could be the problem?

**EDIT**: From what I found about this error, it seems that I `write(...)` after the client disconnects, but how could this be possible?

**EDIT2**: I have debugged the code even more and it seems that one thread (on which runs the `UARTToWifiWorkerSession(...)` function) won't actually exit (because there's a blocking `read(...)` function call at where the execution flow stops). This way that one thread will hang until there's some data received by the `read(...)` function, and when I'm reconnecting there will be created another two threads, this causing some data racing problems.

Can someone confirm me that this could be the problem?

Comment: So, the problem is with the client connecting to the server, correct ? And you have not posted the client side of the code. From what I can guess is that, you are trying to make a connection from the same socket without closing it first.

Comment: @Arunmu I don't have the code from the client side, but what do you think that would be wrong with the client? And what do you mean by saying that I'm using the same socket? There's a new socket for every new connection.

Comment: `Then when I'm trying to connect again..` where is this happening ? Client side or server side ?

Comment: @Arunmu Client side.

Comment: So, when you were saying `There's a new socket for every new connection.` you are talking about the server side, not the client side. What I am guessing here is, your client is trying to make a new connection to the server using an old socket  which was probably not closed.

Comment: @Arunmu Exactly, in all this problem I'm only talking about the sever-side, I don't have access to the client-side code. Then how can I handle this scenario in my code? What should I do in this case?

Comment: Can you check if you are actually receiving something inside this `if(bytesReceived > 0) {` condition ?

Comment: @Arunmu That's exactly why that check is for, it checks if I receive some data from another communication link, if I do, I send it to `TCP` via asio socket. And that's exactly the line where the application crashes, after attempting to do the `boost::asio::write(...)` call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual problem was that the function `UARTToWifiWorkerSession(...)` didn't actually exit (because of a blocking `read(...)` function, this causing two threads (the hanging one, and one of the latest two created ones) to `write(...)` (without any concurrency control) using the same socket.

The solution was to set a `read(...)` timeout, so I can return from the function (and thus destroy the thread) without pending from some input.